# many datatabases in my project I will like to clean it but need information

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net-mvc, database, visual-studio-2012

When I am coming to my project and I go to the Server Explorer under Data Connections, I am seeing 3 connections in red.

```
  - DefaultConnection (Webstore)
  - WebStoreContext (WebStore)
  - WebStoreDBEntities (WebStore)
```

If I go back to the Solution Explorer and I double click inside the App_Data folder (the db file is name WebStoreDB.mdf) , it opens the WebStoreDBEntities (WebStore) database in the Server Explorer.

Should we get rid of the other two red databases DefaultConnection (Webstore) and WebStoreContext (WebStore) ?

Can someone explain me why these 2 other DB are there ?  Any place in the code I should verify and clean up ?

Thanks for your information

Answer (score 0):

A cool thing you can do in visual studio is right click an object and click `find all references` This will show you where the object is used which might help you determine if you should delete - for example `WebStoreDBEntities`

If you are talking about clearing out the server explorer you can clear as many or as little as you feel comfortable clearing. you can always add them back

Comment: Anyway we can directly from Serer Explorer to perform this ?  I would prefer to go to the Web.config instead to check there first and to remove it from there or comment it out.

Comment: The thing is that server explorer will remember db connections from any project that you have added in there. Commenting out a connection string will not remove it. The same is true th other way round. If you delete a db from server explorer it will not remove it from the web.config